# WordPress custom Post Expiry

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I am having issues with the functionality of my code. The custom post should expire after a certain number of days. At the moment it’s set to 3 days just so I can test it.

But the posts are expiring even though the expiry date is before today's date, and I can’t figure out why?!

```
// Setup Cron Job Function to expire posts and send out emails.
function listing_expiry_date() {

    // Get the current date
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $today = date('m/d/Y');
                            
    // Custom Post Type for listings, grab published posts
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => array( 'post_type_listings' ),
        'post_status'    => array( 'Publish' ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    
    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();
            
            // Get the listing ID
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
                
    // Get listing post published date (not pending date)    
    $published_date = get_the_date( 'm/d/Y', get_the_ID() );
    
                                                    
        $expiry_date  = date( 'm/d/Y', strtotime( '+3 days', strtotime($published_date) ) );        
            
        // If todays date is equal to or greater than the expiry date...
        if ( ($today == $expiry_date) || ($today > $expiry_date) ) :

    // change post status to 'expired'
    $postdata = array(
    'ID'          => $post_id,
    'post_status' => 'expired',

        );

    // Update post data
    wp_update_post($postdata);
                                                                                
    endif;                          
            
    endwhile; //endwhile The Loop
endif; //endif The Loop         
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IT seems your issue would be how you're evaluating the dates.  In this case, it would be best to use a Unix timestamp to evaluate which is greater.

```
function listing_expiry_date() {

    // Get the current date.
    date_default_timezone_set( 'Europe/London' );
    $today = date( 'U' );

    // Custom Post Type for listings, grab published posts.
    $args = array(
            'post_type'      => array( 'post_type_listings' ),
            'post_status'    => array( 'publish' ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    // The Query.
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop.
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
            $query->the_post();

            // Get the listing ID.
            $post_id = get_the_ID();

            $expiry_date = date( 'U', strtotime( '+3 days', get_the_date( 'U', $post_id ) ) );
            // If Expiration date is < or = today.
            if ( $expiry_date <= $today ) :
                // change post status to 'expired'
                $postdata = array(
                        'ID'          => $post_id,
                        'post_status' => 'expired',

                );

                // Update post data.
                wp_update_post($postdata);

            endif;

        endwhile; // endwhile The Loop.
    endif; // endif The Loop.

}
```